# Where in North Carolina is this Christmas shopping plaza from Stuck In Love (2012 film)?

Tags: identify-this, north-carolina

[This scene's on You-tube](https://youtu.be/PgMPnCJx7dA). [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2205697/locations?ref_=tt_dt_dt) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuck_in_Love#Production) asseverate [this movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuck_in_Love#Production) was filmed in North Carolina.

> *Stuck in Love* started shooting in [Wilmington, North Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilmington,_North_Carolina) in March 2012, primarily in the [Wrightsville Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrightsville_Beach,_North_Carolina) area.[[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuck_in_Love#cite_note-3)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Stuck In Love Locations's Tumblr](https://stuckinlovelocations.tumblr.com/), this is [The Cotton Exchange](http://www.shopcottonexchange.com/), a "shopping center in historic downtown" located at 321 N. Front Street, Wilmington, NC.

---

Found by using Google's Reverse Image Search on the second image.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't pinpoint the specific shops.